# Calling a constructor function with parameters

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I have a function that I cannot modify and I need to call it, but I haven't seen something like this before.

```
var myCategorize = function(z) {
    return function(q) {
      return 1;
    }
 }('window'.indexOf('w') > 0 || window || false);
```

I have stripped out some of the code in the function(q) portion, just to simplify.

I think I have a curried function, so I tried this:

```
let category = myCategorize(bookTitles[i])(categories);
```

but when I do this I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myCategorize(...) is not a function
```

So maybe this is an anonymous constructor function, so I try something like this:

```
let category = function(){myCategorize(bookTitles[i])(categories)};
console.log(category.apply());
```

I get the same error. How do I call this function and get the return value of 1?

Comment: `myCategorize` refers to the scoped function `function(q) {
      return 1;
    }`, not the outer function.

Comment: What the... `'window'.indexOf('w') > 0` will always resolve to false.

Comment: `myCategorize(x)` will always return 1

Comment: I didn't write the function, please read the question. I know that it will always resolve to false and it will always return 1. I removed the inner code for simplicity and because I am not authorized to publish it.

Comment: @MattKuhns you may not write the function, but with 745 rep you should know it's not [mcve] with those noise.

Comment: @MattKuhns maybe you should reread your question: "How do I call this function and get the return value of 1?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myCategorize` is not a curried function, it's an IIFE implementing the module pattern. The brackets at the very end of the last line execute the top-level `function(z)`:

```
var myCategorize = function(z) {
    return function(q) {
      return 1;
    }
 }('window'.indexOf('w') > 0 || window || false);
//^--------------------------------------------^
```

and pass in the value of `z`. It's clearer if I re-write it to add extra brackets and names bit:

```
var myCategorize = (function outer(z) {
//start of outer --^
    return function inner(q) {
      return 1;
    }
 })('window'.indexOf('w') > 0 || window || false);
//^-- end of outer
```

So what you have assigned to `myCategorize` is just `inner`. To execute it, simply add the brackets and a parameter:

```js
var myCategorize = function(z) {
    return function(q) {
      return 1;
    }
 }('window'.indexOf('w') > 0 || window || false);

console.log("myCategorize", myCategorize);
var executionResult = myCategorize("foo");
console.log("executionResult", executionResult);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks for pointed out the pattern - IIFE implementing the module pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It's already calling the function once when adding the parenthesis, so the value of `myCategorize` is :

```
ƒ (q) {
  return 1;
}
```

Then you call that function with `let category = myCategorize(bookTitles[i])` and the value of `category` is : `1`

so, then equivalent of `let category = myCategorize(bookTitles[i])(categories);` is

`let category = 1(categories);` which throws that error

```js
var myCategorize = function(z) {
  return function(q) {
    return 1;
  }
}('window'.indexOf('w') > 0 || window || false);

let category = myCategorize('x'); // 1

console.log(category);

let category2 = myCategorize('x')('y'); // throws, equovalent to 1('y');
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try that.